# how to make label width auto adjust

Tags: ios, objective-c, width, uilabel, frame

Dynamically lblName text will change.
How to auto adjust label width base on the text content

```
lblName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, auto, 12)];
lblName.font = [UIFont Helvetica12];
lblName.numberOfLines = 1;
lblName.text = Value;
lblName.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
lblName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
lblName.minimumScaleFactor = 10.0f/12.0f;
lblName.clipsToBounds = YES;
lblName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lblName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

Can any one advice me easy way to adjust the label width based on text is set to it.

@All 
Thank You In Advance.

Comment: Call `sizeToFit` on the label after setting the text.

Comment: @rmaddy That means if i set lblName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 200, 12)];  lblName.text = @"abcd"; [lblName sizeToFit];  it automatically adjust the width size?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[lblName sizeToFit];`, which you would do after you set the text. Of course, if you were using Auto Layout, there would be no need for any code to do it.